# How do I merge multiple selected excel files in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new with VBA and I'm wondering on how to merge multiple selected excel files using VBA. I tried coding the part of selecting files. I've researched and tried copying the codes on the internet and did some editing. I learned that you can add filters so I did that. But sometimes, the excel files won't show even if I added the correct filter (based on what I've researched). I really need to merge multiple selected excel files. I hope you can help me.

I'm using a userform, btw. One button that would allow to select and merge the selected files. And if possible, I want the user to see the path of the selected files. I don't know yet on how to do that, or what tool should I use, like listbox or what. Thanks in advance!

**Update!**

I have a code for selecting multiple excel files. What I need now is how to merge the files that I selected.

```
Dim FileNames As Variant
  Dim Msg As String
  Dim I As Integer
  FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)
  If IsArray(FileNames) Then
      Msg = "You selected:" & vbNewLine
      For I = LBound(FileNames) To UBound(FileNames)
          Msg = Msg & FileNames(I) & vbNewLine
      Next I
      MsgBox Msg
      tbPath.Value = Msg
  Else
      MsgBox "No files were selected."
  End If
```

Comment: First, how you want to merge the files??? Adding all the sheets into a new workbook??? Into an already open workbook??? are all the sheets equals or not?? If the sheets has the same names what you want to do???

Comment: All the excel files have only one worksheet and have different names. And I want to have a new workbook/sheet for the merged files. Btw, by excel files I mean workbooks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well here is my code... hope this help you.

```
    Sub mergeAllFiles()

    Dim This As Workbook 'Store the book with the macro
    Dim TmpB As Workbook 'store the book that has the sheets (one per book)
    Dim AllB As Workbook 'book to send all the books
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'the only sheet every book

    Dim FileNames As Variant
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim I As Integer

    Set This = ThisWorkbook
    FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(FileNames) Then
        Workbooks.Add 'add a new book to store all the sheets
        Set AllB = ActiveWorkbook
        AllB.SaveAs This.Path & "\allSheetsInOne" & SetTimeName & ".xlsx", 51
        'The function is to store a different name every time and avoid error
        Msg = "You selected:" & vbNewLine

        For I = LBound(FileNames) To UBound(FileNames)
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileNames(I)
            Set TmpB = ActiveWorkbook
            TmpB.Activate
            Set sht = ActiveSheet 'because you say that the book has only one sheet
            sht.Copy Before:=AllB.Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'send it to the end of the sheets
            TmpB.Close 'we don't need the book anymore
            Set TmpB = Nothing 'empty the var to use it again
            Set sht = Nothing
            Msg = Msg & FileNames(I) & vbNewLine
        Next I
        MsgBox Msg
        tbPath.Value = Msg
    Else
        MsgBox "No files were selected."
    End If
End Sub


Function SetTimeName()
Dim YY
Dim MM
Dim DD
Dim HH
Dim MI
Dim SS
Dim TT

YY = Year(Date)
MM = Month(Date)
DD = Day(Date)
HH = Hour(Now)
MI = Minute(Now)
SS = Second(Now)

TT = Format(YY, "0000") & Format(MM, "00") & Format(DD, "00") & Format(HH, "00") & Format(MI, "00") & Format(SS, "00")

SetTimeName = TT
End Function
```

Tell me if is need it any improvement.

Comment: Thank you for the code. However, I got an error from the line 
sht.Copy Before:=AllB.Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'send it to the end of the sheets
It says that the subscript is out of range.

Comment: How many books you import??? Which version of excel are you using??? Did you run the code using F8 (step by step) or any button (let the macro run)???

Comment: Currently, I have 5 workbooks but the program should be flexible, merging different numbers of workbooks. I'm using Excel 2010. When running the code, I just press F5. I'm using a userform.

Answer (score 0):

### Use my code from here:

[Multi-Select Files and open](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Open%20Multiple%20Files)

Edit the code to suite your requirements.

```
Sub OPenMultipleWorkbooks()
'Open Multiple .xlsx files
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim wb As Workbook, bk As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim GetFile As Variant, Ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet

    For Each Sheet In Sheets
        If Sheet.Name <> sh.Name Then Sheet.Delete
    Next Sheet

    ChDrive "C:"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    GetFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="XLSX(*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Open XLSX- File", MultiSelect:=True)

    On Error Resume Next

    If GetFile <> False Then

        On Error GoTo 0

        For i = 1 To UBound(GetFile)

            Set bk = Workbooks.Open(GetFile(i))
            Sheets(1).Move Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
            bk.Close True
        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```